# plot jQuery flot chart is not displaying in IE

Tags: jquery, charts, plot

plot jQuery flot chart is not loading in IE, but it is working fine in chrome and in firefox.

I have included `excanvan.min.js` also. Even though it is not working in IE. Please help. Below is my code.

```
function drawchart()
{
  var data = [];
  var series = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
  for( var i = 0; i<series; i++)
  { 
    data[i] = { label: "Series"+(i+1), data: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1 }
  }

  $("#chart1").height($("#pan1").height()); 
  $.plot($("#chart1"), data, 
  {
    series: {
      pie: { 
        show: true,
        radius: 0.8,
        label: {
          show: true,
          radius: 2/3,
          formatter: function(label, series){
            return label+'<br/>'+Math.round(series.percent)+'%';
          },
          threshold: 0.1
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      show: true
    }
  });
}
```